# Is there any way to expedite propagation domain registrar change?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have made a mistake.  I changed domain registars from Network Solutions to Gandi.  The record is properly configured at Gandi and all of the "alternative" name servers (google, opendns) have updated and work properly.  However, the major ISPs in my area (Belgacom or EDPNet) are still querying the Network Solutions name servers and returning a "domain not found" error. Effectively, the site is not available for most people.

Is there any way to expedite this change?  If not, is there any way to tell how long these name servers will wait before they start querying Gandi?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory yes, you can see how long it will take for their cache to expire.  When you query their resolvers they should display the decreasing TTL for NS record of your domain.

`dig @nameserver ns <yourdomain>`. Assuming your allowed to query their dns servers that is.

You can't really expedite that cache time-out AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, now at least I can tell my boss how long this will last.